# AudioContext createScriptProcessor randomly stops with no error

Tags: javascript, web-audio-api

I'm connecting the microphone input node, `getUserMedia({audio:true})`, to a `createScriptProcessor` node and the `onaudioprocess` event callback just stops happening and I cant figure out why.

I print out the events for each callback. One in the middle looks like this:

```
AudioProcessingEvent {outputBuffer: AudioBuffer, inputBuffer: AudioBuffer, playbackTime: 5.479909297052155, clipboardData: undefined, path: NodeList[0]…}
bubbles: true
cancelBubble: false
cancelable: false
clipboardData: undefined
currentTarget: ScriptProcessorNode
defaultPrevented: false
eventPhase: 0
inputBuffer: AudioBuffer
outputBuffer: AudioBuffer
path: NodeList[0]
playbackTime: 5.479909297052155
returnValue: true
srcElement: ScriptProcessorNode
target: ScriptProcessorNode
timeStamp: 1417920765179
type: "audioprocess"
__proto__: AudioProcessingEvent
```

And the last one looks like this:

```
AudioProcessingEvent {outputBuffer: AudioBuffer, inputBuffer: AudioBuffer, playbackTime: 5.944308390022676, clipboardData: undefined, path: NodeList[0]…}
bubbles: true
cancelBubble: false
cancelable: false
clipboardData: undefined
currentTarget: ScriptProcessorNode
defaultPrevented: false
eventPhase: 0
inputBuffer: AudioBuffer
outputBuffer: AudioBuffer
path: NodeList[0]
playbackTime: 5.944308390022676
returnValue: true
srcElement: ScriptProcessorNode
target: ScriptProcessorNode
timeStamp: 1417920765643
type: "audioprocess"
__proto__: AudioProcessingEvent
```

Looks no different to me. I would've expected the event to contain some kind of notification. Or at least an error in the console.

Is there a way to bind to some kind of error event or something? I'm not sure how to trouble shoot this further. Sometimes it stops after a millisecond. Sometimes after minutes. I cant seem to determine what the problem is.

Answer (score 3):

That sounds like a garbage collection. Can you point to the code?

Comment: that could totally be it. How do I do that? [Here's the code](https://github.com/ccorcos/meteor-webaudio). Do I need to `delete` any object that was created with `new`? Also, are any dev tools that show this?

Comment: yeah, so this is definitely the issue. for some reason, I though javascript magically solves this for you. I suppose I like functional programming more...

Comment: So I'm not sure how to figure this out. I deleted the `new` objects I created. When I look at the timeline in chrome developer tools, it looks like a sawtooth wave. So it seems memory just keeps building up then getting dropped. I'm not sure where its coming from though...

Comment: Try sticking your `ScriptProcessorNode` onto an object that will exist for the lifetime of your application. Like `window.obj = {}; obj.processor = audioContext.createScriptProcessor( 2048, 1, 1 )` or whatever.